# Div's text is highlight on multiple clicks

Tags: html

I'm trying to stop my `<div>`'s text from highlighting when I click on it multiple time (it's a button). I know that there is a solution but I just don't know it. This is a simple and easy question to answer.

```
<div id="Button01">Time?</div>
```

And yes, I know it's a stupid question to ask...

Comment: I would just add a background image but the client doesn't want that...

Comment: Why don't you use a `button` element instead if it should be a button?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1319126/prevent-highlight-of-text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when it's a div it can't be a button. When you click some text multiple times is a standard behaviour the text gets highlighted.
There is some code I found on SO

```
div{
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
```