# How to keep hover states in Chrome while mouse is pressed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, dom, event-handling

I'm stopping a `mousedown` event when my users press on a custom dropdown list. This is to avoid the default text-highlighting behaviour of the browser while the user is effectively dragging the mouse.

I'm doing this with a jQuery `event.preventDefault()` call in the handler function and returning false.

This has the desired effect, except that in Chrome it also prevents CSS `:hover` states to work while the mouse is still pressed.

Firefox doesn't suffer the same problem. The text highlighting is cancelled, and the :hover states continue to work as the user rolls over items with the mouse still pressed.

Is there a method that will work in Chrome too?

I could add further `mouseover` handlers to add custom classes, but I'd prefer a more graceful solution so I can use the :hover pseudo classes in my CSS.

Comment: Looks like the text-highlighting and event stopping are red herrings. Chrome just doesn't seem to activate :hover states with the mouse pressed. I may resorts to JS mouseovers

Comment: When you say custom dropdown do you mean something made up log list items and anchors?

Comment: yes. the items being rolled over are `<li>` elements

Answer (score 0):

Well to prevent highlighting of text, there is a CSS3 property for that.
I found this info in a SO question." [Prevent Highlight of Text Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1319126/prevent-highlight-of-text) "

EDIT: I think this one " [How to disable text selection highlighting using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826782/css-rule-to-disable-text-selection-highlighting) " is better because there are more browsers covered thus making it more cross-browser.

Comment: Interesting. It certainly stops the selection. But Chrome still refuses to do the :hover states with the mouse pressed. I guess this shows that the text highlighting is a red herring.

Answer (score 0):

You could define your CSS as
    :hover, .hover { ... }
And then just toggle the class on mouseover

Comment: I may end up doing that although in my question I stated that I'd rather not.

Comment: Sorry I missed the last bit of your post. I'm going to blame my iPhone :)

Answer (score 0):

On document mousedown just add this class to the body:

```
.stopSelect {
-webkit-touch-callout: none;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-khtml-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
}
```

This will prevent text selection.
On mouseup remove the class.

Comment: good to know about this, as mentioned already in the answers. This property doesn't enable the :hover states while 'dragging' though. I'm handling this with JS mouseovers, although I didn't want to.