# Make text in div used as button not markable

Tags: html, text, appearance

I really like the concept of using `div` elements as buttons. Above all the complete freedom of styling it is a real benefit in my opinion to do so.

The problem I got now is following: in a little project of mine I have a section where a user can input some values in order to store this data. Such a single input element containing input fields and other input elements is used to record one bill. In order to allow the user to input more than one bill, I've made a `div` based button which adds one further input element per click.

[image]

Now, let's say a user wants to record 8 bills, he will click 7 times on this button, and this in a fast manner. You know that if you double click text, it gets marked, which results in a very ugly appearance of the button.

[image]

Is there any way to set a div attribute for ''text not markable''? I'd really love to solve this without images.

Comment: did you try: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2310734/how-to-make-html-text-unselectable

Comment: I'm sorry, ''to select'' was the word I searched instead of ''to mark'' (I'm not native english).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From this very site:

```
#yourTable {
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
```

[Credit goes here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1319158/785241).  Remember that IE won't always care, either.